# WordPress import database error

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm moving my localhost based website to the live server, I uploaded all the files to the server. After that, I created a new database, when I came to import my old database SQL file that I exported from the localhost, I got this error :

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 2

Line 2 in my SQL file :

-- version 4.1.14

Comment: can you paste in `line 2` of your SQL file?

Comment: Sure, I updated the post

Comment: When MySQL is reading a long sql file, the line numbering in syntax error reports is useless, unfortunately. It restarts the line count with every statement. You need to look for a statement with a question mark on the first, second, or third line. Better yet, use one of the migration plugins to move your web site, like @BasilBaby suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think your server mysql is older version. Try to use any plugin to move your localhost wordpress site to server

plugins

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

and
https://ithemes.com/purchase/backupbuddy/

try any of these two.

Comment: Is there a way to update the server SQL to the latest version ?

Comment: A 1064 error is  a syntax error in the sql code which is not supporting on server sql.

try PHPmyAdmin export sql file to older version